# How does sb2 in the below code holds abc but not abcd?

Tags: java, data-structures, stringbuffer

```
    StringBuffer sb1 = new StringBuffer("abc");
    StringBuffer sb2 = new StringBuffer(sb1);

    sb1.append("d");

    System.out.println(sb2);
```

Since StringBuffer is mutable and sb2 points to sb1, i would expect sb2 to have "abcd" as the value.
Though the question is layman, could you please help me explain this.

Comment: Also as per StringBuilder docs *it is recommended that this class be used in preference to StringBuffer*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StringBuffer creates a new object in Heap on calling `new StringBuffer(sb1)`. It does not point to `sb1`.
If you wish to make `sb2` point to `sb1`, then declare   `StringBuffer sb2 = sb1`

> `public StringBuffer(String str)`
>
> Constructs a string buffer initialized to the contents of the
>   specified string. The initial capacity of the string buffer is 16 plus
>   the length of the string argument.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the code `StringBuffer` there is no constructor which take **StringBuffer**, instead below constructor and because `StringBuffer` implements `CharSequence`  thats why this works.

```
public StringBuffer(CharSequence seq)
```

Your code is not working because its not appending `StringBuffer` instead content of it.

From [public StringBuffer(CharSequence seq)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#StringBuffer-java.lang.CharSequence-)

> Constructs a string buffer that contains the same characters as the specified CharSequence. The initial capacity of the string buffer is 16 plus the length of the CharSequence argument.

Comment: and even if there was such a constructor it would very likely clone the contents